# How are parenthesis used in Regular Expressions with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

It seems to me parenthesis have two meanings in regular expressions:

1- they are used to capture - as in:
`/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/g`

2 - they are used to group - as in: 
`/(phone|#)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g`

Is there a way I can indicate that the regex should group on one expression and capture on another - It seems there should be a different notation for each.

Comment: Note that your understanding is a bit wrong: 1 - is used to group and capture but the group has only one alternative, 2- is used to group and capture with the group containing two alternatives. `()` has only one meaning - group (which implies capture). The `?:` modifier disables capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define non-capturing groups like this:

```
/(?:phone|#)/
```

The `?:` right after the opening parenthesis indicates that it should not capture anything.